# how to convert multiple else if statements to ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would i convert this `if/else` statement into a `ternary operator` instead of using if/else statements. I know this is simple to most javascript developers, but its confusing to me.

```
  if(this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 0) {
        return null
  } else if(this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 1 ){
      return <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping[0]} is typing...</p>
  }
   else if(this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length > 1){
        return <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')} are typing...</p>
  }
```

My attempt was something like

```
 {this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 0 ?  (
          null
 ): (
     <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping[0]} is typing...</p>
 )}
 // not sure how to include the 2nd else if statement in this ternary operator
```

Comment: Nested ternary operators are bad and highly confusing. Use a switch case instead.

Comment: or i can stick with an if/else statement, this would be considered "clean enough code" right ?

Comment: Switch is even faster. Check the code below.

Comment: I'd rather think to cache those lenghty to variable to encourage the work of minifier.

Comment: My take: https://codesandbox.io/s/1v556xj14j

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback but got the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intentions correctly, there is no need for a ternary.

Example:

```
render() {
const { usersWhoAreTyping } = this.props

return (
   <div>
    {usersWhoAreTyping.length === 1 && <p>{usersWhoAreTyping[0]} is typing...</p>}
    {usersWhoAreTyping.length > 1 && <p>{usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')} are typing...</p>}
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Great! Just a general tip: try to always destructure the props of a component. Makes things a lot more readable, and you avoid doing multiple `this.props.xxxxx` https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md

Answer (score 1):

```js
switch (this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length) {
  case 0:
    {
      return null
    }
  case 1:
    {
      return <p > {
        this.props.usersWhoAreTyping[0]
      }
      is typing... < /p>
    }
  case 2:
    {
      return <p > {
        this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')
      }
      are typing... < /p>
    }
  default:
    return null
}
```

Try this if its okay for you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but i do not want to use a switch statement, i want to use a teneray, if not then i will keep it the way it is.

Comment: Cool. But switch is more efficient. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/

Comment: If 3 or more people are typing what's going to happen

Comment: Use the condition in default.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend sticking to the if/else, as nested ternaries can be confusing to people. But here's how you'd do it:

```
{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 0 ? (
  null
) : this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 1 ? (
  <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping[0]} is typing...</p>
) : (
  <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')} are typing...</p>
)}
```

Note: i did make the assumption that the 3 cases cover all possibilities. Ie, length can't be less than 0 or be a fraction. Since we're presumably dealing with an array, that seemed reasonable, and it let me drop the length > 1 check.

Comment: thx, just what i was looking for, however would have to go with @mattemyo solution.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, and writing out your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Using a ternary operator is simple just this:

```
  const result =
    this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length > 0 ? (
      this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.length === 1 ? (
        <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping[0]} is typing...</p>
      ) : (
        <p>{this.props.usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')} are typing...</p>
      )
    ) : null;
```

Take into account I modified the conditions due to get the case less than 0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above nested ternary operators can be confusing and should be avoided. But if you really want to write code without multiple if/else, you can refer this. It uses some ES6 features.

```
const { usersWhoAreTyping } = this.props;

someFunc = () => {
    if(usersWhoAreTyping && usersWhoAreTyping.length) {
        const translation = usersWhoAreTyping.length === 0 ? 'is' : 'are';
        return <p>{ `${usersWhoAreTyping.join('and')} ${translation} typing...` }</p>
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, *technically* you could do what you're asking like this:

```js
function showTypers(aArrayOfNames) {
  var iArrayLength = aArrayOfNames.length;
  
  return (iArrayLength === 0) ?
         null :
         '<p>' + ((iArrayLength > 1) ?
                   aArrayOfNames.join(' and ') + ' are' :
                   aArrayOfNames[0] + ' is') +
         ' typing...</p>';
}

console.log(showTypers([]));
console.log(showTypers(['Tom']));
console.log(showTypers(['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']));
```

That being said, I honestly wouldn't recommend nesting this particular scenario, specifically because one of the outcomes (`length === 0`) results in a completely different outcome than the other two (amongst other reasons . . . nested ternary logic can be very confusing).  I'd recommend something more along these lines like this:

```js
function showTypers(aArrayOfNames) {
  var iArrayLength = aArrayOfNames.length;
  var sUserNames = "";

  if (iArrayLength > 0) {
    sUserNames = (iArrayLength > 1) ? aArrayOfNames.join(' and ') + ' are' : aArrayOfNames[0] + ' is' ;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  
  return '<p>' + sUserNames + ' typing...</p>';
}  
  
console.log(showTypers([]));
console.log(showTypers(['Tom']));
console.log(showTypers(['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']));
```

Comment: appreciate you're feedback.